# Как удалить функцию BASH?

Tags: bash, shell

В `.bash_profile` я прописал функцию

```
function hs()
{
    ( cd ~/folder/Homestead && vagrant $* )
}
```

но видимо допустил какую-то ошибку, так как при вызове, например, такой команды `hs ssh` вылазит ошибка `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ssh'`, при этом изменение функции `hs` + `source .bash_profile` не помогает, не помогает также `unset -f hs` , даже удаление файла .bash_profile ни к чему не приводит, команда `hs` все равно работает и выдает ошибку. Как такое возможно?

Comment: хм.... Мне кажется, в `bash` есть своя функция `test`, может тут какие-то накладки получились?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов к сожалению не в этом проблема, в оригинале функцию вообще называется hs такой функции в BASH нету

Comment: может тогда оформите вопрос как нужно? не вижу проблем скрывать имя функции

Comment: `declare -F` покажет список известных башу функций, `declare -f` - с кодом.

Comment: @KoVadim команда вывела обновлённую версию функции, но при вызове все равно отрабатывает старый вариант

Comment: а почему Вы считаете, что отрабатывает "старый вариант"?

Comment: Запустите `hash -r`.